# OpenERP - How I can remove Save button and Discard link from my view?

Tags: odoo

How I can remove Save button and Discard link from my view? I have created very simple view but the Save and Discard buttons are there by default. Please see the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In your `ir.actions.act_window` xml record, add this line

```
<field name="target">inline</field>
```

I know this is an old question. Just in case someone googled this question and stumble across this.

Comment: And someone did, six days later. I had to 'upgrade' my module before the change became apparent, even after reloading the old view with developer mode active.

Comment: Someone else did, six years later!  Many thanks!  :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is actually pretty easy to accomplish.

If you want to hide the buttons `Create` and `Import` in a Tree View, use `create="false"` in the tree tag definition:

```
<record id="your_id" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">your.model.tree</field>
    <field name="model">your.model</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Your model" create="false">
                <!-- Your fields-->
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

If you want to hide the buttons `Save`, `Edit` and `Discard` in a Form View, use `create="false"` and `edit="false"` in the form tag definition:

```
<record id="your_id" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">your.model.form</field>
    <field name="model">your.model</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Your model" create="false" edit="False">
            <!-- Your fields -->
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: That won't work in case where people can create objects but shouldn't be able to save them. Accessing a new object by clicking create from the tree will open a form that has a save button anyway. It makes it virtually impossible to add a "confirm" dialog before creating.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily hide by adding simple below jquery script in xml.

```
<form>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".modal-header").hide();
        $(".modal-footer").hide();
        });
    </script>
    <group col="4" colspan="4">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can easily hide by adding the simple style below in XML.

```
<form>
    <style>
       header{
          display:none !important;
       }
       footer{
          display:none !important;
       }
    </style>
</form>
```

Thanks